# Porque div me ocupa el height: 100% sin indicarselo

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Porque el div con clase `iconmas` me ocupa en altura 100% sin decirselo,solo le indico `padding 0 0.5%`

```css
.padre
{
position:relative
}

.ttcategoriax
{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.ttcategoriax p
{
 position: relative;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: aqua;
 padding: 3%;
 width: 100%;
 display: block
}

.iconmas
{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto;
 width: 15%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
 padding:0 0.5%
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
 <div class="ttcategoriax"><p>Electronica</p></div>
  <div class="iconmas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por naturaleza los div intentan ocupar el máximo contenido de la etiqueta padre.

Comment: eso no es en el width?

Comment: Aunque esto es cierto (normalmente), es falso en este caso, pues si revisas el código, tiene posicionamiento absoluto dentro de un contenedor con posicionamiento relativo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está ocupando el 100% del alto porque tiene posición absoluta y le estás diciendo que su posición de arriba `top` es en 0, y lo mismo abajo `bottom`, por lo cual el elemento "intenta" cumplir estas dos instrucciones y su borde superior está en lo más alto del contenedor referencia (el cual tiene posición relativa) y su borde inferior en lo más bajo.

Si le quito `bottom: 0;`, entonces ya no ocupa el 100%, para mostrarte que esa es la razón principal.

```css
.padre {
  position:relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.ttcategoriax
{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.ttcategoriax p
{
 position: relative;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: aqua;
 padding: 3%;
 width: 100%;
 display: block
}

.iconmas {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
 margin: auto;
 width: 15%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
 padding:0 0.5%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
 <div class="ttcategoriax"><p>Electronica</p></div>
  <div class="iconmas">holaaa</div>
</div>
```